# Mac terminal: Deleting files from a folder whose name is equal to files in another folder

Tags: macos, bash, shell, terminal

The layout of the two directories in question is:

```
folder1
-file1
-file2

folder2
-file1
-file2
```

The files in the directories are named the same. I tried to use `rm` to programmatically remove files in folder 2:

```
for f in /Users/michelegiarratana/1/*; do rm /Users/michelegiarratana/2/$f
```

but this isn't working. Is `$f` the full path? How do I get the name?

Thanks

Comment: Use `basename`: `for f in /path/to/folder/1/*; do rm "/path/to/folder/2/$(basename "${f}")"; done`

Comment: It still sees me rm: /Users/michelegiarratana/2/*: No such file or directory

Comment: That probably means that there are no files in `/Users/michelegiarratana/1/`.

Comment: no, both have the same files inside

Comment: The `*` character gets expanded by `bash` to "all files in the directory". If there are files under /Users/michelegiarrantana/ **1** /, then the `*` will get replaced by those file names. However, your error message is `rm: /Users/michelegiarratana/2/*: No such file or directory`. This happens when there are no files for `*` to expand. In this case, it gets treated as a literal `*` character, ie. `basename $f == '*'`. So you are literally running `rm /Users/michelegiarratana/2/*`.

Comment: you are right but the folder does actually contains files...so I don't understand...for f in /Users/michelegiarratana/1/*; do rm /Users/michelegiarratana/2/$(basename "${f}"); done; should make it

Comment: In that case I don't understand either. Sorry, I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

As savanto said in his comment -- yes, you are correct, `$f` here is the full file path. To fix this, you should use the `basename` builtin, which extracts just the file name. In your example:

```
for f in /Users/michelegiarratana/1/*; do rm /Users/michelegiarratana/2/$(basename $f); done
```

Additionally -- your question applies more broadly to bash shells than just the OS X terminal, in the future, you should try looking for answers in the `bash` tag, as many of them will be useful to you.

Comment: My preference would be to use Bash's substring capabilities, rather than calling basename (which I don't believe is actually a builtin, per http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html). So I'd replace `$(basename)` with `${f##*/}`.